# redis replication change master node

Tags: redis

I have a Redis cluster deployed using Kubernetes, one master node with two slave nodes.
Because of the failover issue or something else, the master node has changed.

I know that apps can connect to sentinel and choose the master node, but this is not my point.

I want to know if it's possible to change (choose) the master node by force using k8s ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

You have to call the **sentinel** service first which will return the **Master** and **slave** service IPs.

However, if you will set up a cluster with `Master-slave` and fix the *Master* service type it will work.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster

There is two thing in redis

One with **sentinel** and the other with **sharding**.

> Choose between Redis™ Helm Chart and Redis™ Cluster Helm Chart You can
> choose any of the two Redis™ Helm charts for deploying a Redis™
> cluster. While Redis™ Helm Chart will deploy a master-slave cluster
> using Redis™ Sentinel, the Redis™ Cluster Helm Chart will deploy a
> Redis™ Cluster with sharding. The main features of each chart are the
> following:

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster#introduction but there limitation and depends on the use case.

By default only one service is exposed. You will connect your client to the exposed service, regardless you need to read or write. When a write operation arrives to a replica it will redirect the client to the proper master node.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster#cluster-topology