# Redis statefulset kubernetes manage write and read requestes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, devops

I have a redis statefulset running on my cluster, with 3 nodes (master, slave, slave), the master node is for write only, and the other 2 nodes for read, they replication is working fine, but I want to connect a backend application to this redis-cluster and somehow manage the requests, in which the write requests goes to master and the reads goes to slaves, any idea how I can achieve this ? Does it have to be controlled in application level, or is there any solution in Kubernetes to achieve this?

In addition, I want to know about the situation when I am scaling up the statefulset replicas or scale down, then the traffic direction still should be going to appropriate pod.

My Kubernetes cluster is running on premises.

Comment: at kubernetes level, have you looked into possibility of using a load balancer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you have setup the Redis and you are running the **Redis cluster** or running **Redis master-slave** with **sentinel** option.

[Official doc](https://redis.io/docs/management/sentinel/)

If you have used **helm chart** they have the option to enable the **sentinel**.

```
sentinel:
  enabled: true
```

Check this [Github Doc](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis#choose-between-redis-helm-chart-and-redis-cluster-helm-chart) there is two helm charts or topology available and which one you have used.

So the idea behind sentinel is it writes or gives you back the **current IP** of the master and slave.

For example below the python code snippet, when you will hit the service of **Redis** it will give you both **master** and **slave IP**, you can use it as per need either **write** or **read**.

```
from redis import Sentinel
sentinel = Sentinel([('<**Single K8s service Name**>', 26379)], socket_timeout=0.1)
sentinel.discover_master('mymaster')
('127.0.0.1', 6379)
sentinel.discover_slaves('mymaster')
[('127.0.0.1', 6380)]
```

**Reference** : https://github.com/redis/redis-py#sentinel-support

Ref for few more answer might be helpful :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68551193/5525824
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271427/5525824
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454335/5525824

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using helm charts, but I will look at the configMap to see if I can add thsi option to the configuration.

Comment: sure, i think it would be possible depends on the image you are using, never get a chance to look at CM-level config. give it try and please feel free to share the details there please.